# maven does not use 64 bit jvm

Tags: java, maven, java-8, 64-bit

I am facing a weird issue in maven.

I am running java 1.8 in 64 bit windows .
When I run java -version I get the below message

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

I am running maven 3.3.9 on the above jdk.

When I run mvn -version I get the below message

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T19:41:4
7+03:00)
Maven home: D:\Users\57181\Projects\mvn\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.
9
Java version: 1.8.0-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\java\java8\java8\jdk1.8.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

However when I run mvn -d64 -version , I get below error

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

I need to build a very large project using maven which needs 2 GB heap.
Though my machine has 8 GB RAM , I am not able to set the heap since Maven is running in 32 bit( In the task manager , the process shows as * 32 )

Has anybody faced this issue ?

Is there any configuration needed to run maven in 64 bit JVM ?

Comment: What's the output of `echo %JRE_HOME%`?

Comment: JRE is pointing to D:\java\java8\java8\jdk1.8.0\jre

Comment: And what does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` say?

Comment: D:\java\java8\java8\jdk1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You are picking up the default JVM installed for web page plugins etc as it is in your PATH.

You can put the JDK directory first in your PATH environment variable which most likely is the simplest.

You may also choose to set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK you want to use, either as part of your environment or by modifying the `mvn` script.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk 1.8 .  Also tried placing the jdk first in the PATH